# Package Manager Console Does Not Load

Tags: visual-studio-2013, nuget

Any ideas of why my Nuget Package Manager Console suddenly does not load (greyed out)?

[image]

I have tried opening the console from within different contexts/projects without luck.

If it was to throw an error on console startup, where could I catch possible error messages? Output window is empty.

I am using Visual Studio 2013 Premium with Nuget Package Manager v2.8.

Comment: I am seeing this a lot with vs2015

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reinstalling Nuget fixed this issue.

I am, however, still unaware of what caused such behavior.

Comment: You probably don't need to reinstall nuget. I find PM hangs sometimes. On the off chance that you closed the window during that time it will be grayed out. Just restart visual studio

Answer (score 1):

Hiding the console window is what grayed it out for me...  I uninstalled/reinstalled Nuget package and then I restarted VS and it came back :)